# How to keep a command running in loop in browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, css-selectors

I have a web element that only appears while the page (or a part of the page) is still loading and disappears when the page has been completely loaded. I would like to see precisely when this element disappears and I can do that by repeatedly running something like that in the browser console:

```
$("div.v-app-loading")
```

or alternatively:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('v-app-loading')
```

But in most cases everything happens too fast and I am unable to catch the exact moment. There must be a way to create a loop that will just run in the console and execute one of the commands I mentioned say every 0.5sec or even more frequently.

Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: @epascarello thanks. is that question really that bad it deserves a downvote?

Comment: Someone thought so

Comment: @epascarello thanks again :)

Comment: @epascarello just noted that the loop stops running when I navigate to another page. Which exactly when I want it to run. Anything I should do differently?

Comment: Only option is to load it when the next page loads

Comment: @epascarello yeah, that's exactly the problem I wanted to solve as I won't have enough time to do that. The page loads fairly quick.

Comment: so stick a break point in the first script on the page. Execute your code, resume execution

Comment: Maybe you are solving the wrong problem

Comment: @epascarello I have the same feeling. I just need to verify the behavior I mentioned in my question and that's the only way I had in mind. If you think there is a better way, I am all ears.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Javascript's `setInterval()` as following:

```
function yourFunction(){
    //do something here...
}
setInterval(yourFunction, 500); //Will run the function every half a second(500ms = 0.5s)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But if I run it this way, it stops just when I navigate to another page. I want it to run continuously.

Comment: The only way for you to do that is to run it from the console and have `preserved log` checked (in chrome) and you must be on the same tab because of the sandbox. You can not preform this from a webpage...

Comment: preserve log is not going to run the Javascript on the next page load.

Comment: You are correct, sorry for the miss leading (`preserve log` will just save the JS output that has been excuted). Just remember that chrome is very serious with sandboxing...

Comment: This is incorrect code and will run once. You meant `setInterval(yourFunction, 500)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's easier to use jQuery to detect when the page is loaded:

HTML

```
<body class="loading">
```

JS

```
// do something initially here

$(window).load(function () {
    // do something when finished loading
    $('body').removeClass('loading');
});
```

Edit: If you rather wanted to check for existence of an elemtent, do it in a recursive function call. You can throttle it with setTimeout, but you don't need to:

```
function checkElement() {
    if ($('.v-app-loading').length) {
        checkElement();
        // or: setTimeout(checkElement, 100);
    } else {
        // Element disappeared
    }
}

checkElement();
```

Comment: Well, that's exactly the point. The page itself might appear as loaded but some widgets on that page are still loading so in that case I will get a false positive. Moreover, I specifically need to ensure the behavior I have described when this webelement actually disappears only when everything on that page has loaded.